# Get data usage since last reboot by command line

Tags: windows, networking, command-line

For an automated batch-tool that monitors network usage, I would like to get the following, red underlined values using the Windows command line:

[image]

That is, I want to get the number of bytes uploaded and downloaded (network activity) since the last system reboot using a command (Windows 10).

I already tried `netstat -e` (using this command: `for /F "tokens=2,3" %%a in ('netstat -e ^| find "Bytes"') do set "received=%%a" & set "sent=%%b"`), but for some reason, it outputs almost ten times as many bytes as the control panel.

So how can this be done?

Comment: may be netsats output is in bits. Try multiply it with 8 and compare it.

Comment: @totti `netstat` explicitly says "Bytes"...

Answer (score 6):

If it's OK to use the PowerShell, use the [`Get-NetAdapterStatistics` cmdlet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj130889%28v=wps.630%29.aspx).

`PS C:\> $stat = Get-NetAdapterStatistics –Name WiFi
PS C:\> $stat.ReceivedBytes
70081089484
PS C:\> $stat.SentBytes
137824135690`

There is a [blog post about getting network adapter statistics](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2014/01/17/gathering-network-statistics.aspx) using PowerShell at technet.

Comment: If I execute these commands, they only output 0 for me. Even if I just type `Get-NetAdapterStatistics` all numbers are zeroes, although the control panel clearly shows a value of more than 100 megabytes.

Comment: There has to be something broken then. Try to run it in an elevated command prompt and as another user and see if that changes anything.

Comment: In case this helps, it's also something I'm also having a problem with.

The basic Get-NetAdapterStatistics command is producing output of 0 bytes for only two of my interfaces: named "Ethernet 2" (a disconnected adapter via onboard) and "Bluetooth Network Connection".  However, my actual network is "Ethernet".  I tried to add -InterfaceDescription "Ethernet" but it says there's no object found with that property.

This was attempted with both elevated and non-elevated PowerShell prompts using both x86 and x64 variants.

Comment: None of these methods change anything. I also tried turning WiFi off and on and reactivating it in the control panel, but nothing changes.

Answer (score 0):

Both the `netstat -e` and the Connection Status box use "Bytes" as the Unit.

netstat -e has existed for a long time, so -i assume- would be bugfree.

BUT, netstat may be counting all interfaces, including loopback.

I did not believe it before either, but Powershell (as indicated by Josef above) seems to be the route of least friction.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out a solution that works. I compared the netstat's and control panel's output and found out that netstat shows almost exactly 6 times (yes, six. this is completely illogical...) as many bytes as the control panel. So you just have to divide `netstat -e`'s output bytes by six and you have the real data usage.

Comment: I suspect that bytes are being counted multiple times as they pass through filters such as packet inspection, virtual adapters, etc.  The multiplier you're seeing may likely vary from system to system.